# bcp export format file invalid name specified or access denied

Tags: sql-server, bcp

In cmd, I'm trying to create a `fmt` file, my code is

```
bcp Database1.dbo.Table1 format nul -c -x -f c:\format.xml -T -S .\sql2005
```

Then I get error saying Format file could not be opened. Invalid name specified or access denied.

I wonder how I can check if the access is denied or not? And how I can give access the permission?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your file to the root of the C: drive if you have UAC enabled then you would need to run your CMD prompt as an administrator to get access to write to that location. If you create a sub-folder like c:\BCPTest\ then you should be able to write to that folder.

Comment: I still get same error from both SSMS and CMD when run as administrator. Please help